# Columns of matrix $A_{m \times n}$ span $\mathbb{R}^{m}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding the following theorem given in my textbook:

> Let $A$ be an $ m \times n $ coefficient matrix. Then the following statements are logically equivalent (That is, for a particular $A$, either they are all true or all false statements.)
>
> *a*) For each **b** in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, the equation $A$ **x** = **b** has a solution.
> *b*) Each **b** in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. 
> *c*) The columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. 
> *d*) $A$ has a pivot position in every row.

I understand that *a, b, c* are restatements of each other. I would like some intuition on why statement *d* and the others (particularly *c*) are logically equivalent.

Comment: @GitGud Added explanation for logically equivalent.

Comment: I think you should say equivalent, rather than logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the answer to this in most introductory linear algebra textbooks but a quick answer would be as follows:

- If for each $b$, you have a solution to $Ax=b$, it implies that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. If this were not true, then they would only span a subspace of $R^n$ and if we chose a vector $b$ which was not in this subspace, the above statement would not hold.
- Since $Ax=b$ can be written out as $\sum_i A_i x_i =b$ where $A_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ column of A and since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent and span $R^n$, they form a basis for $R^n$ and thus, any bector $b$ can be written out as a linear combination of the basis and hence of the columns of A.
- All of the above statements imply that the matrix is full rank and invertible.
- If one started a Gaussian Elimination on A and found a row where there was no pivot, then the matrix is not invertible which contradicts the above statement.
- Another way of thinking about it is that through Gaussian Elimination (or Gauss-Jordan Elimination), you are trying to "create" an identity matrix on the left and the solution for $Ax=b$ on the right. If you are unable to find a pivot in any position, it implies that you are unable to span the whole space since you are constraining the possible RHS.

Comment: In the first bullet you said that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, but there are matrices which have linearly dependent columns and still have a solution for all $b$.