# Prove that column vectors of a matrix $A $ {span} $(\mathbb{R^m})$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove the following statement: Given an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, if $Ax=b$ is consistent for all $b$ then the column vectors of $A$ span $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: I think this answer can be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293099/columns-of-matrix-a-m-times-n-span-mathbbrm?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can solve the system $Ax=b$ for every $b$ then the application $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ given by $f(x)=Ax$ is surjective. Try to prove that the column vectors of $A$ span $\Bbb{R}^m$ if and only if the application defined above is surjective. (in the end, if you do the computations, you arrive exactly at the definition)